# Community cleanup of tagless questions

Tags: discussion, tags

[There are a number of untagged questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

These should probably be either:

- tagged
- deleted
- edited/reopened

Quite a few of you have more than 10k reputation ([required for deleting questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)) and can vote to delete these, if needed. Everyone can edit them and anyone with 3k rep can vote to reopen.

We'd love for the community to decide the fate of these - rather than simply deleting them all ourselves.

Discuss/vote/edit away!

---

[How should I calculate task value in hours?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/40831/how-should-i-calculate-task-value-in-hours)

[How can I create a disclaimer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/36553/how-can-i-create-a-disclaimer)

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/34310/need-an-advice-for-my-future

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21269/is-my-boss-trying-to-take-my-skills

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18869/senior-colleagues-chase-me

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17863/is-the-pomodoro-technique-useful-in-an-open-plan-office-without-headphones

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/16601/what-does-this-reply-mean-or-imply

[What is a polite way to avoid endorsing a letter/email submitted to you by a subordinate?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/37001/what-is-a-polite-way-to-avoid-endorsing-a-letter-email-submitted-to-you-by-a-sub)

[Liability for company development equipment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18544/liability-for-company-development-equipment)

[How To Prepare for a Project Manager Role Technical Interview](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14535/how-to-prepare-for-a-project-manager-role-technical-interview)

[How much power does a 'project manager' have?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/33863/how-much-power-does-a-project-manager-have)

Comment: Why do we have an 'untagged' tag? Is it to aid new users who cannot quite figure out what to do with the tags? And how are they able to figure out *that*?

Comment: @Happy questions which are migrated, the tag removed, etc.  A few edge cases.

Answer (score 3):

I see that [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18869/how-do-i-ask-why-my-senior-colleagues-are-following-me-around) has been heavily edited in an attempt to bring it back on topic. May be worth a look. I don't have the rep to vote to re-open and flagging it didn't seem to be the right way to go either.

Comment: It looks like this was edited, migrated away, and came back (migration rejected), after which the OP deleted it.  It had two reopen votes, so I left a comment for the OP about that.  If it gets undeleted we can take another look.

Answer (score 2):

My thoughts on the questions:

How should I calculate task value in hours?
- too localized, **recommend deletion**.

How can I create a disclaimer? 
- Has a good answer, **retag** and leave closed.

Need an advice for my future
- Title says it all, **recommend deletion**.

Is my boss trying to take my skills
- Duplicate, I editied the tag, we should **leave it closed**.

senior colleagues chase me
- Currently very much a 'my situation sucks fix it', I already retagged it, **could be reopened with a hero edit, otherwise delete it**.

Is the Pomodoro Technique useful in an open plan office? (without headphones)
- Migrated question, I already retagged it, if it got an **edit to focus the aim of the question** it might be able to be reopened.

What does this reply mean (or imply)?
- Too localized, **recommend deletion**.

What is a polite way to avoid endorsing a letter/email submitted to you by a subordinate?
- **already dealt with**! Thanks Roger!

Liability for company development equipment
- Already retagged by Roger! **Recommend *against* deletion**

How To Prepare for a Project Manager Role Technical Interview
- Too broad, tags already cleaned up by Roger, **Recommend deletion**.

How much power does a 'project manager' have?
- Too localized, already retagged by Roger, **recommend deletion**.

Comment: I did a big cleanup of the "chasing" question - deleted a lot and tried to focus it - but I'm not sure if it's enough. I focused on "how can I ask why they're doing it?" but it might be better to go with the (perceived) prejudice angle.